# Storing selected row in array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do we stor selected row in array in JavaScript?

Comment: More information please.

Comment: The selected row of what? Please provide a small, but complete example of the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud be more specific in what kind of object youre using in your html (DOM) code.

exampl: 
if you're using a SELECT 'resources' in a form

```
var fl = form.resources.length -1;

//Pull selected resources and add them to list
for (fl; fl > -1; fl--) {
   if (form.resources.options[fl].selected) {
    theText  = form.resources.options[fl].text;
        theValue = form.resources.options[fl].value);

        //your code to store in an aray goes here
        //...
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it you want to store selected table rows using javaScript.
If yes, this may help. 
This piece of code is to accumulate selected ID's (dataId), based on selection of selected row's id(elemId), in an input (hidId).
I have modified my original code to maintain the records in an Array as well.

```
function checkSelection(hidId,elemId,dataId)
{
    var arr =
    str = '_' + dataId + '_';
    hid = document.getElementById(hidId);
    row = document.getElementById(elemId);
    if(!row.classList.contains("selected")) {
        row.classList.add("selected");
        if(!hid.value.toString().includes(str)) {
            hid.value = hid.value + str;
        }
        if(arr.includes(dataId))
            arr.push(dataId);
    }
    else {
        row.classList.remove("selected");
        if(hid.value.toString().includes(str))
            hid.value = hid.value.replace(str,"");
        if(!arr.indexOf(dataId)==-1)
            delete arr[arr.indexOf(dataId)];
    }
    alert(arr.toString());
}[I have tested it][1]
```

to focus more on the Array() a basic solution would be as below:

```js
function checkSelect(hidId,elemId,dataId)
{
    row = document.getElementById(elemId);
    str = "";
    if(document.getElementById(hidId).getAttribute("value")!=null)
        str =   str+document.getElementById(hidId).getAttribute("value");
    str= str.replace('[','')
        .replace(']','')
        .replace('"','')
        .replace('\\','');
    document.getElementById(hidId).setAttribute("value",str);
    alert(document.getElementById(hidId).value);
    var arr = new Array();
    if(document.getElementById(hidId).value.length!=0 ) {
        arr=document.getElementById(hidId).value.split(',');
    }
    if(!row.classList.contains("selected")) {
        row.classList.add("selected");
        if(!arr.includes(dataId.toString())) {
            arr.push(dataId.toString());
        }
    }
    else {
        row.classList.remove("selected");
        if(arr.includes(dataId.toString()))
        {
             delete dataId.toString();
            arr.splice(arr.indexOf(dataId.toString()),1)
        }
    }
    if(arr.length>0) {
        document.getElementById(hidId).setAttribute("value", arr.toString());
    }
    else
        document.getElementById(hidId).setAttribute("value", "");
}
```