# row selected row using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

In my MVC Razor project I am showing data in rows (list format).
These values are shown using javascript Knockout.

I want to higlight the selected row using javascript KnockoutJs.
Is there a better way of doing this.

Here is my code

```
<ul class="navlist" data-bind="foreach:selectOptions" >                    
    <li><a href="#" data-bind="click:selectOption">
        <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
        <span data-bind="text:option"></span>
        <span data-bind="text:optiondate"></span></a>
    </li>                                        
</ul>
```

Comment: how do you know the selected row??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VbwSm/1), it's pretty simple.

As you can see i store the the selected option in an observable.
And the databind applies the 'highlight' class if the selected option is the current option.

```
<ul class="navlist" data-bind="foreach:selectOptions" >                    
    <li>
        <div data-bind="click:$parent.selectOption, css: {'highlight' : $parent.selectedOption() == $data }" style="cursor: pointer">
        <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
        <span data-bind="text:option"></span>
        <span data-bind="text:optiondate"></span>
        </div>
    </li>                                        
</ul>
```

View model :

```
vm = {
    selectOptions : [{name:'name1',option : 'option1',  optiondate:'optiondate1'},
                     {name:'name1',option : 'option2',  optiondate:'optiondate2'},
                     {name:'name3',option : 'option3',  optiondate:'optiondate3'}],
    selectOption :  function(opt){
        vm.selectedOption(opt);
    },
    selectedOption:  ko.observable()
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: You have some typo... remove trailing comma `selectedOption:  ko.observable(),` and missing "d" `<span  ata-bind="text:name"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

I have posted something useful here:
[Storing selected row in array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295234/storing-selected-row-in-array-in-j)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvGBB.png)avascript/61581214#61581214